# Unable to gosip from one region to another on Amazon with ec2multiregionsnitch

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

I'm trying to launch a multi region cluster using the ec2multiregion snitch.
The nodes in one DC can communicate. But when adding nodes from another DC they fail with the following error:

> ERROR [main] 2016-05-09 10:57:01,88
>   CassandraDaemon.java:581 Exception encountered during startup
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any seeds

I have installed dse on an ubuntu 14.04 and have 4 nodes running in a cluster in Frankfurt (2 on subnet a and 2 on subnet b).
The problem arise when I try to add more nodes from Ireland.

I have added the following ports to the security:

> 80
>   8984
>   7199
>   61620
>   7000 - 7001
>   61620 - 61621
>   8983
>   7077
>   443
>   4040
>   8888
>   22
>   7080 - 7081
>   7080
>   9160
>   9042

Then I made the following settings in the cassandra.yaml file

```
listen_address: local ip
rpc_address: local ip
seeds: "public ip seed 1, public ip seed 2"
endpoint_snitch: Ec2MultiRegionSnitch
broadcast_address: public ip
```

What more do I need to setup for them to communicate?

Comment: Do all of your nodes have EIPs? Did you open the ports in both regions? For testing, open the ports to 0.0.0.0 in security group. [Change cassandra-rackdc.properties file to specify the data center](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureSnitchEC2MultiRegion_c.html).

Comment: My nodes does not have EIP's but they do all have public IP's which is the IP's I also use for specifying the seeds. The ports I have listed above is open in both regions and they all accept connection from 0.0.0.0/0. I have now edited thr cassandra-rack-proerties so it has the following lines

`dc=DC1`
`rack=RAC1`
`dc_suffix=_1_cassandra`
`prefer_local=true`

The dc_suffix is also set to `_2_cassandra` in other nodes.
This works on the first DC nodetool report two DC in eu-central. But the gossip protocol can still not connect from another region.

Comment: I checked my notes and I also set rpc_address to 0.0.0.0 in cassandra.yaml

Comment: I changed the rpc_address to 0.0.0.0. Then it asked me to set the broadcast_rpc_address. So I have set that to the public IP's of the nodes. But same error occur  on nodes from the second DC `can not gossip with any nodes`

Comment: can you telnet from one DC to the other on port 9042 on the external ip? If you can't, then there may be a network issue.

Comment: yes it is possible to telnet from DC1 to DC2 and also from DC2 to DC1. Its strange as Im using the exact same shell script to install the nodes in both DC.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with cassandra community version 3.2 and instead using the GossipingPropertyFileSnitch and then it worked